# Assigning selected values of a column of given data frame to another data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to assign selected column values of a data frame to another data frame.

```
data = [['Math',87],['Geography',93],['Physics',72],['Geometry',75],['Astronomy',81],['English',94],['History',84]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Subjects','Grade'])
df

Subjects  Grade
Math         87
Geography    93
Physics      72
Geometry     75
Astronomy    81
English      94
History      84
```

I have another data frame:

```
data2 = [['Astronomy'],['Geography'],['Geometry'],['History']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['Subjects_selected'])

df2

Subjects_selected
Astronomy
Geography
Geometry
History
```

How can I assign the Grade column values to the df2 as new column elements automatically?  I wish to get:

```
Subjects_selected   Retrieved_Values
Astronomy                       81
Geography                       93
Geometry                        75
History                         84
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and selecting column `Grade`:

```
df2['Retrieved_Values'] = df2['Subjects_selected'].map(df.set_index('Subjects')['Grade'])
print (df2)
  Subjects_selected  Retrieved_Values
0         Astronomy                81
1         Geography                93
2          Geometry                75
3           History                84
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and rename columns:

```
d = {'Subjects':'Subjects_selected','Grade':'Retrieved_Values'}
df2 = df2.merge(df.rename(columns=d), how='left')

print (df2)
  Subjects_selected  Retrieved_Values
0         Astronomy                81
1         Geography                93
2          Geometry                75
3           History                84
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned select , I will using `isin` , which is '*more like to select* '

```
df.loc[df.Subjects.isin(df2.Subjects_selected)]
Out[93]: 
    Subjects  Grade
1  Geography     93
3   Geometry     75
4  Astronomy     81
6    History     84
```